# How to display right-to-left written ancient characters in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, character

I have a project which must support multiple ancient languages. My problem is that I have an ancient Old Turkic character (the language is written right-to-left) but I can't display the characters in a Qt Label like this:

```
//main.cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include <QString>
#include <QLabel>

int main(int argc, char** argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QString str = "\U00010C00"; // Character I wanted to display
    QLabel *label = new QLabel(str);
    label -> show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

When I run this, in the label it prints a square which indicates that, I think, the character couldn't be found. How can I fix this problem?

A square is being displayed at the right of the window, so there is not a problem with the location of the character.  My OS is Ubuntu 12.04 x64 and my Qt version is 5, by the way. I have the Old Turkic Unicode font.

Comment: The square usually indicates that your selected font does not have a glyph for that code point.

Comment: But I have the font. It shouldn't display the square :(

Comment: @BoraSemiz Have you tried converting it? `QString::fromUtf8(const QString &)`

Comment: You have a font with that glyph installed, but have you *selected* that font for use in Qt? Does `str` actually end up holding the right data? Not rhetorical, I am not familiar with Qt -- but the interpretation of `\U` notation (or any non-ASCII-7 character, actually) is implementation- and locale-dependent, so I'd double-check. Try what happens if you fill `str` with the correct / expected encoding (UTF-8? UTF-16?) manually, using octal / hexadecimal escapes.

Comment: What about `QFont` + `QLabel::setFont()` ?

Comment: @ElderBug yes, I have just tried, but I get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the label which font it should use.

```
QFont labelFont = QFont( "Old Turkic" );
label->setfont( labelFont );
```

Comment: It doesn't seem work. I still get the same result, but the size of the square is changed.